# I am trying to switch every empty cell to one filled with the number 1

Tags: openpyxl

Hi I am currently using  openpyxl and am trying to swap every empty cell to one with the number 1, and then eventually one filled in with red. Here is my code so far:

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl.styles import Color, PatternFill, Font, Border
from openpyxl.utils import column_index_from_string

#redFill = PatternFill(fill_type=None, start_color='F2DCDB', end_color='F2DCDB')




wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('MRR.xlsx')
sheet = wb["Monthly MRR "]

for r in range(7, 793):
    for col in range(4,21):
        current_cell = sheet.cell(row=r, column=col).value
        if current_cell == None:
            current_cell = "LL"


wb.save("updatedMRR.xlsx")
```

Even though I loop through every item, it does not seem to change any of the cells.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change your code so that you refer to the actual cell and explicitly check and set its value. Your code currently checks a copy of the value and then overwrites the copy but not the actual cell.

`current_cell = sheet.cell(row=r, column=col)
   if current_cell.value is None:
       current_cell.value = "LL"`

PS use `ws.iter_rows()` rather than your own counter.